# How to create ECDSA key pair without openssl

Tags: c++, public-key-encryption, ecdsa

I am writing a cross-platform application in c++. I would like to know if it is possible to create an ECDSA key pair (public key and private key) without using any external library, just pure c++. Any answer leading me to the right path would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anything can be made in C, are you asking how? Perhaps start by reading [some](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SignHash-and-VerifySignatur-fab7c8c2) of the [source](http://www.cryptopp.com/)

Comment: ECDSA is publicly documented at http://secg.org so of course you can write a C++ program that implements it.  However, this question is too broad for StackOverflow.  You can try implementing it and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.